# Does it use less power to process and compress data on a chip, or to transmit it to a station?

Tags: microcontroller, wireless, low-power

Let's say I had a grid of force resistors laid out in a pad. Every 5 minutes I'd apply power to the pad and read the resistance of every force resister. The pad itself would be powered by a battery, and would remotely connect to a base station and upload all the data. The connection would be over low power 2.4ghz.

When it comes to uploading the data back to the base station, I had two ideas.

1. Simply send all the raw data to the base station and let it deal with all the calculations.
2. Keep the old values in memory, and before upload compare the values to the old ones and only send updated values.

My question is, would it use more power to compute what data to send first, or just to send all the data without doing any calculations on it?

Comment: I don't know, but I think sending data will take a lot more power than performing a simple check. The other thing, though, is that you might be able to put the pad in a deeper sleep state if you don't have to "remember" the old values. If that is the case, then it may cancel out some of the benefits of not transmitting.

Comment: To add to what mkeith commented: The answer depends on too many variables. Which microcontroller? Which wireless protocol? If you use ZigBee, as an example, your packet size will likely be the same whether you transfer all of the data or just a subset. If your data is floating point, an 8-bit micro may burn more cycles processing the data than it's worth.

Comment: You may find that sending large packets less often saves power over regular small transmissions, regardless of the compression aspect.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much power you use to transmit the data, versus how much power you use to process the data.

Given you have such a wide choice of hardware and protocols, and your transmission range and environment is not specified, the question is completely unanswerable, without many more details.

Your way forward is to choose some transmission hardware, and some processing hardware, and estimate their power consumption. Then see whether lower power stuff exists, rinse and repeat. Then buy the best you can afford of each, program it, and choose the best.

A few hints, bluetooth is much lower power than WiFi, though the latter would give you a more capable connection, if you like shh'ing into remote computers. Consider 6LoWPAN as a protocol. Some processors built for smart meters have very low power consumption, some processing, and a radio built in, like a TI CC1110 for instance. For one-off, buying the manufactuer's dev board is a good way to go.